# X-scrollwheel in Windows

Tags: windows, mouse, mouse-wheel

Is there any way to have mouse-wheel events sent to whatever window is underneath the mouse pointer, even if it's not the active window? I'd like to have x-scrollwheel capabilities without having to turn on x-mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is supported in Windows natively, but a program called KatMouse should do just this:

> The prime purpose of the KatMouse utility is to enhance the functionality of mice with a scroll wheel, offering 'universal' scrolling: moving the mouse wheel will scroll the window directly beneath the mouse cursor (not the one with the keyboard focus, which is default on Windows OSes). This is a major increase in the usefullness of the mouse wheel.

[KatMouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/)

Comment: I'm already using KatMouse, but it doesn't always seem to do the trick.

Comment: N/M, I'm an idiot who needs to RTFD. Still, it doesn't work for some apps, like Document Explorer.

Comment: Autohotkey would make it trivial to send, say, a mouseclick to the down button next to the scrollbar.

Comment: KatMouse uses proper wheelmouse semantics for windows, and can be configured to do scroll mouseclicks for windows which don't support wheelmouse messages, per-application and per-window. It's a cinch to set up that way, too. KatMouse wins for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Autohotkey!

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
SetWinDelay, -1
SetBatchLines,-1
SetKeyDelay, -1

; acceleration
_WHEELACC=0x280000
; max speed
_WHEELMAXN=0x1800000
; automatically activate window
_WHEELAUTOFOCUS=1

return


EasyWheel(d)
; if _WHEELAUTOFOCUS if set, check which window is under the mouse and gives it focus if it hasn't already
; then send scroll event to the control under the mouse
; original code from Shimanov: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6772#54821
{
Global _WHEELACC
   , _WHEELMAXN
   , _WHEELAUTOFOCUS
Static t, s


   if ( A_TickCount > 500+t) {
      t := A_TickCount
      s :=0x780000
   }
   else if (s < _WHEELMAXN)
      s += _WHEELACC

   MouseGetPos x, y, hwnd
   h := DllCall("WindowFromPoint", "int", x, "int", y)
   if _WHEELAUTOFOCUS && (hwnd<>WinExist("A"))
      WinActivate, ahk_id %hwnd%
   SendMessage, 0x20A, d*s,(y<<16)|x,, ahk_id %h%
}


WheelUp:: EasyWheel(1)
WheelDown:: EasyWheel(-1)
```

(Taken from the thread linked in the script comment)

AHK can do anything :3